# JavaFX ObservableList Concrete Implementation

Tags: java, javafx, jaxb, javafx-8

I have classes that are generated from an XSD using JAXB.  One of the options with JAXB custom bindings is to specify the `java.util.List` implementing class.  For example, I can specify JAXB uses the class `java.util.LinkedList`, and the generated code would include the following:

```
if (myList == null)
    myList = new java.util.LinkedList();
```

I would like the implementation to return a `javafx.collections.ObservableList`, but can't find any concrete classes that implement that interface and have a default constructor.  Does anyone know of a concrete implementation of `javafx.collections.ObservableList` with a default constructor?

Comment: Have you tried FXCollections.observableArrayList(); It Creates a new empty observable list that is backed by an arraylist.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not writing the code... it is generated by JAXB.  I can only tell the code the type to instantiate, and that type must provide a default constructor.

Comment: Can you make your own? Extend one of the existing ones you found and provide a default constructor in your new class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, there are two ways to go about doing this.  The first is to implement your own `javafx.utils.ObservableList`.  The following implementation is provided in the documentation for [ModifiableObservableListBase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ModifiableObservableListBase.html) (slightly modified):

```
public class ObservableArrayList<T> extends ModifiableObservableListBase<T> {
    private final List<E> delegate = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public E get(final int index) {
        return delegate.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return delegate.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdd(final int index, final E element) {
        delegate.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected E doSet(final int index, final E element) {
        return delegate.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected E doRemove(final int index) {
        return delegate.remove(index);
    }
}
```

JAXB can then use this class as the implementing list type, by adding the following to the bindings file:

```
<bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='Item']">
  <property name="Items" collectionType="myNamespace.ObservableArrayList">
    <baseType name="myNamespace.Item" />
  </property>
</bindings>
```

The second option, and the one I decided to use, is to configure the JAXB marshaller/unmarshaller to use custom implementation classes that inherit from the generated classes.  Lets say that the XSD defines a complex type with the name "ItemCollectionType", that contains an element definition with the name "Item" and with unbounded `maxOccurs`.  Then I simply add the following to the JAXB bindings file:

```
<bindings node="./xsd:complexType[@name='ItemCollectionType']">
  <class implClass="myNamespace.ItemCollection" />
</bindings>

<bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='Item']">
  <property name="Items">
    <baseType name="myNamespace.Item" />
  </property>
</bindings>
```

The above forces every occurance of `ItemCollectionType` in the generated code to be replace with type `myNamespace.ItemCollection`.  Then, the generated implementation of `ItemCollectionType` includes the following code:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Item", required = true, type = myNamespace.Item.class)
protected List<myNamespace.Item> items;

public List<myNamespace.Item> getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = new ArrayList<myNamespace.Item>();
    }
    return this.items;
}
```

Then, I override this method in `myNamespace.ItemCollection`:

```
@Override
public ObservableList<Item> getItems() {
    if (!(super.getItems() instanceof ObservableList)) {
        items = FXCollections.observableList(items);
    }
    return (ObservableList<Item>)items;
}
```

Of course, these two options are NOT mutually exclusive.  I could easily implement them both, which would simplify the implementation of `myNamespace.ItemCollection.getItems` to a simple cast.

Comment: Your implementation looks similar to `ObservableListWrapper`.

Answer (score 2):

This static function will get you a concrete implementation of `ObservableList`:

```
FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```